# Sort api using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to sort a particular value from api and sort them `asc` or `desc`
for example if i give `sort = price` & `sort = 1` it should sort the price `asc`.

The below mentioned is my JSON format -

```
{
    "name": "iphone x",
    "brand": "iphone",
    "price": 12000,        
},
```

I just need to get the brand or something i request in the api and need them to be sorted asc or desc
http://localhost/product?sort=brand&orderby=asc

My code is -

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let brand = req.query.brand;
    let select = parseInt(req.query.select);
    let name = req.query.name;
    let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    let skip = parseInt(req.query.skip);
    let orderby = req.query.orderby; 
    let sort = req.query.sort; 
    let value1 = parseInt(req.query.value1)
    let value2 = parseInt(req.query.value2)

    const sortObject = []; 
    sortObject[sort] = orderby === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    const result = await product
      .find({ "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } })
      .select()
      .sort(sortObject) 
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .exec();

    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Error " + err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `.sort({price:1})` ?

Comment: I need to get the value dynamically from the api for example if sort = author&orderby=asc or sort=name&orderby=asc

Comment: You can use JS variables if you want, in the same way you are using `skip` or `limit`.

Comment: yes but the issue is i need to get both what i need to sort and in which order how can i get both from a single constant or how to combine both const

Answer (score 1):

Given that, Your URL to query is -

`http://localhost/product?sort=brand&orderby=asc`

You want to sort based on `brand` and order `asc`.

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
 
  try {
    let brand = req.query.brand;
    let select = parseInt(req.query.select);
    let name = req.query.name;
    let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    let skip = parseInt(req.query.skip);
    let orderby = req.query.orderby; // this is a string you're getting not integer
    let sort = req.query.sort; // you need to get this also

    const sortObject = {}; // create a blank sort object
    sortObject['sort'] = orderby === 'asc' ? 1 : -1; // set the sorting 
    const result = await product
      .find({brand:brand})
      .select()
      .sort(sortObject) // need to pass sortObject here.
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .exec();
   
    res.json(result);
   
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Error " + err);
  }
});
```

Based on the value of orderby, you need to set the sort order.
`1` for `asc`, `-1` for `desc`. We are storing that to `sortObject` and then we need to pass that to `.sort()`

Comment: You can also use `asc` and `desc` to sort, check [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort), so, ensuring values from the URL are correct, it is no necessary to use `orderby === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;` (btw this comparsion also need to ensure values are correct) you can simply use the object `.sort({sort:orderby})`

Comment: Thanks for info. I wasn't aware :) I left the comparison part to handle all cases to the person(I thought he should be able to do that :P)

Comment: the process doesn't work for me it is requesting the sort object as string like "brand:1" example: .sort("brand:1")

Comment: You need to provide object inside `.sort()` and not just simple string. What is the error you're getting

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta sortObject['sort'] the sort does not get regcotied because it a string so converted to  sortObject[sort] , then i passed the .sort(sortObject) but its not sorting its throws a error brand not defined

Comment: Can you please add/update your code here?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta  see the above code i have modified

Comment: @officiallyforlearning you have defined sortObject as array which should be an object.

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta      const sortObject = {}; 
    sortObject[sort] = orderby === 'asc' ? 1 : -1; i tried but not displaying the brand in asc or desc order

Comment: How can we see the output what you're getting?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta i get the output in postman  the brand is displayed in normal way how data are stored in the mongo by the way can u check the $gt and $ls its also not working i am getting the value but it does not work

Comment: If `find()` is not working properly then I would suggest to do it step by step. If possible try the mongo shell first.

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta $gt is working but sort is not working i tried a lot but its not working